# Execution stuck when evaluating TensorFlow tensors

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

So my code is:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:    
    init.run()
    epoch = 1
    iteration = 1
    print("Checkpoint 1")
    X_batch, y_batch = tf.train.batch([X_train, y_train], batch_size=batch_size)
    print("Checkpoint 2")
    X = X_batch.eval()
    y = X_batch.eval()
    print("Checkpoint 3")
```

The problem is that when executing the 2 last lines the execution stuck, not giving any output (Only checkpoint 1 & 2 are printed). I've searched across google and the conversion from `tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor` to `numpy.ndarray` seems to be a trivial operation .

I also tried the following in case it makes some difference:

```
X = X_batch.eval(session = sess)
y = X_batch.eval(session = sess)
```

**Edit:** I tried using Interactive session and the problem remains

```
`sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
 X_batch, y_batch = tf.train.batch([X_train, y_train], batch_size=batch_size)
type(X_batch)
type(y_batch)
print(type(X_batch.eval()))
sess.close()`
```

Comment: Try running parts of your code using an interactive session in a ipython shell:
Type: 
import tensorflow as tf 
tf.InteractiveSession()
See if this helps...

Comment: @ma3oun I edited the initial post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start the `queue` runner hidden in `tf.train.batch` by using for example a `tf.train.Coordinator` (have look to [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/reading_data) or [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/threading_and_queues) for example to get more insight). As per the docstring of the method (highlights from me):

> This function is implemented **using a queue**. A `QueueRunner` for the
>         queue is added to the current `Graph`'s `QUEUE_RUNNER` collection.

and

> The returned operation is a **dequeue operation** and will throw
>     `tf.errors.OutOfRangeError` if the input queue is exhausted. If this
>     operation is feeding another input queue, its queue runner will catch
>     this exception, however, **if this operation is used in your main thread
>     you are responsible for catching this yourself**.

As you didn't start the queue runner, the thread get stuck waiting for the enqueue operation to be run.

```
    X_batch, y_batch = tf.train.batch([X_train, y_train], batch_size=batch_size)
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(init)
        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
        try:
            while not coord.should_stop():
                X, y = sess.run([X_batch, y_batch])
        except Exception as e:
            coord.request_stop(e)
        finally:
            coord.request_stop()
            coord.join(threads)
```

Comment: Shouldn't you pass the OutOfRangeError to the `coord.request_stop()` ?

Comment: Could you add some comments as to why and in particular why catching `Exception` ? Avoid Exception, e use `as e` not python 3 compatible

Comment: @Nicolas Thanks for your reply. Do you have any clue why the implementation I tried didn't work ? While searching stackoverflow, it was the recommended one.

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D, you want to be sure that all the threads are indeed stopped in case of any issue on one of them, so the exception catching to request the remaining ones to stop by themselves.

Comment: @lacrima, I believe the reason was that you didn't start the thread to run the enqueue operation hidden in `tf.train.batch`.

Comment: Yes they have a peculiar clean_stop_exception_types that by default is `(errors.OutOfRangeError,)` - thanks ;)

Comment: Yes, the `OutOfRangeError` is the queue TensorFlow equivalent of the python `StopIteration` exception.